# Payara keeps giving 404 error for index.xhtml

Tags: jsf, http-status-code-404, payara

So im working on a Java ee application with payara. I wanted to try JSF to setup some webpages. But whatever i try, i cant get my application to find the index.xhtml page. It looks like i configured everything correctly. My guess is that my artifact wont take my jsf files when it gets deployed, but i have no clue on how to check this.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
     version="4.0">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

my glassfish-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN"
"http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

These files are in the directory like,
project/source/main/webapp/WEB-INF/

and my index.xhtml is in the webapp directory.

Does anyone have any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the directory structure of your `war` file? There might be an issue with your war structure

Comment: I got the normal war, its like: projectname.war->projectname:war exploded, then i got the war:exploded artifact and this one is like: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
and 
WEB-INF/classes/projectname compile output
WEB-INF/lib
and i got a seperate projectname module 'WEB' facet resources

Comment: try answer given by Don. I think it will fix your problem

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me.  I remove the leading "/" from the path in the welcome file and it works for me after that.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Did you ever get it fixed?  I'm curious what the problem ended up being.  The comment about posting the folder structure in the war is always important, also if you are using maven, the pom.xml and knowing the maven version can help.